# Configuration issues extjs6 in laravel5.3 project?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, extjs

I created laravel5.3 application successfully. It is simple login app.
 Initially I used  blade templates for the app and later I used extjs4

Now I want to use extjs6. 0.

I am getting  below issues.

I created ExtJS app in  the Laravel public folder.
  And from the routing I want to load index page.

[image]

In laravel route:

```
Route::get('/extshow', function(){
    return View::make('extjspage');
});
```

Extjspage.php

```
  <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" data-app="feecee0f-b576-4366-967e-78fffdbb1023" type="text/javascript" src="../myapps/see/myapp6/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

from the browser:`localhost/extshow`

error:
[image]

localhost is pointing to /public directory

if I localhost to change /see/myapp6/ then it works but, it will become a problem for laravel initially loading, and routing.

how can make extjs6 index load using laravel in above case?

My apache configuration this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/simple-laravel-login-authentication-master/public
<Directory /var/www/html/simple-laravel-login-authentication-master/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

and created ExtJS app in  /public/myapp6.

while loading ExtJS from PHP.

file are not getting because /myapp6 path is missing , so how to reference this files in the correct way?

Comment: what does the error read when you click on it you should reference your js by src="/anysubfolder_inside_public/filename.js"

Comment: file not found is coming ,if I click on error link

Comment: you are not referencing the files correctly in your view. anything you put in the public directory will be accessible as such if the file name is main.js you want to reference that in your html as src="/main.js"

Comment: Yes, those are accessible, the only problem within creating Sencha app, where to set my custom path to access the files correct manner.

Comment: Generally, Sencha application able access all files for creating an app folder, in  my case it's trying access after myapp6/

Comment: In my case http://localhost/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1473855267306 has to change to http://localhost/myapps/see/myapp6/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1473855267306. where to change this?

Comment: is this using gulp or grunt or something?

Comment: It is using Sencha Cmd

Comment: all i can tell you without actually seeing the structure is that you're referencing the files wrong

Comment: yes , referencing is not right, what could be the correct way to do it?

Comment: see edits in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a standalone ExtJS app using sencha command.
after creating app, just copy the all created folder and paste them into public laravel folder.Then from the php we can load the extjs application.